# Make Fabric.js object draggable but not "selectable"

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

[Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) has this really cool aspect where it allows, by default, all objects to be "selectable", which means they are able to be dragged, resized, and rotated. However, I would like for them to be draggable only, no resizing or rotating. Is this possible? I don't mind mucking with the source if that is what's needed, it would be better than reimplementing it myself.

Answer (score 11):

Nevermind, I have found the answer here: http://fabricjs.com/customization/

This is the line that does it

```
canvas.item(0).hasControls = false;
```

Comment: Either that or you could also go with lockRotation=true and/or lockScalingX=true and/or lockScalingY=true

Answer (score 9):

on creation pass following options to object:

```
hasBorders: false
hasControls: false
hasRotatingPoint: false
```